# proper calculation for javascript time differences from server roundtrip

Tags: javascript

trying to get difference in time handled for a game, but I haven't been able to get the math right (My weak point). Heres what I have so far:

```
function(timeSentToServer, serverTime) {
    var difference = serverTime-timeSentToServer
    var roundTripTime = Date.now()-timeSentToServer;
    var responseTime = roundTripTime-difference;
    timeDifference = responseTime;
}
```

timeSentToServer is the Date.now() when the request was sent. This is required due to multiple requests, and this function isn't within the scope of the function that sends the request.
serverTime is the time when the server received the request

the timeDifference should be a value that I can add to Date.now() to match it up with the current serverTime (probably a few milliseconds off, but thats acceptable)

however, I am running into an issue where one device Im testing against is just one second ahead of the server, and its throwing the whole calculation out of whack

e.g.: currentTime: 968952 sentTime: 968834 serverTime: 967742 difference: 1210

which results in being even more ahead of the server.

will Date.now()-difference be the solution I'm looking for? and also, is there any other articles I can read on the subject, and any different solutions?

Comment: Isn't `timeSentToServer` also calculated on the client side? Why are you even using serverTime here (are you? It's in the arguments list)

Comment: Yeah there is a bit of redundancy, I will update to reflect that.

Comment: The critical timing for these purposes is from your server, So using javascript you really just want to start with "now" from the server and tick seconds from each request.